# How to differentiate between null and missing mongogdb values in a spark dataframe?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Pre-requisite: The schema of MongoDB documents is unknown.
It has null values and missing values:
For instance CCNO in the following documents
(1) has value
(2) has null value
(3) is missing.

I am fetching them in spark using MongoSpark.load(SparkSession, ReadConfig), but it is replacing missing values with nulls in the dataframe.

**Please suggest a way to differentiate between the manually inserted nulls and spark inserted nulls(for missing values).**

[image]

Comment: Updating a response in another thread

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/apache-spark-mongodb-dataframe-issue-td37958.html